# Dependency Injection non interface constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am using Unity and am wanting to do the following: I basicly want to pass a value type into the base constructor.

Here is a typical InterfaceL

```
public interface Irepo
{

void test();
}
```

Here is the implemented class, I want to be able to also inject a non interface into the constructor. is this possible?

```
public class Repo : baseRepo, Irepo
{
public Repo(IOther other, string username) : base(username)
{}
public void test(){}
}
```

Here is this unityconfig:

```
container.RegisterType<Irepo, Repo>();
container.RegisterType<IOther , Other>();
```

Ive tried this, but it says Repo doesn't have a parameter that takes a string. Anyone have any ideas?

```
container.RegisterType<Irepo, Repo>("user", new InjectionConstructor("user"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're providing an `InjectionConstructor` to supply the arguments for a constructor, then you need to supply them all, even if they are registered interfaces themselves.

```
container.RegisterType<Irepo, Repo>("user", new InjectionConstructor(
    container.Resolve<IOther>(),
    "user"
));
```